# I need help about apply method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, methods, apply

As an absolute beginner in JavaScript, I had to choose some good source to help me to learn it. I chose "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" by David Flanagan and so far I think that everything in this book is thoroughly explained, but I came up to the point where I'm stuck...

And here's the problem, in chapter "Functions"->"Argument Types" there's an example of a function which adds numbers or elements of an array. This function can accept any number and type (if it can convert it to number) of arguments. The code goes like this:

```
function flexisum() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var element = arguments[i], n;
        if (element == null) continue;
        if (isArray(element))
            n = flexisum.apply(this, element);
        else if (typeof n === "function")
            n = Number(element());
        else
            n = Number(element);

        total += n;
    }
    return total;
}
```

What confuses me is the line where recursion occurs, I can't figure out to what value does **n** evaluates. If, for example, **element = [1,2,3]**, **flexisum(1,2,3)** is assigned to **n**... But how can I add that value to variable **total** if **n** doesn't have initial value, or does it?

English is not my native language, so I hope that I was clear enough... I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `total` has an initial value of `0`. Or do you mean that `n` doesn't have an initial value? That doesn't matter because `n` is guaranteed to have a value through the `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

`n` doesn't need an initial value. When you make the recursive call, that invocation has its own copy of all the variables. It initializes its copy of `total` to `0`, then loops through its arguments. In this case, the arguments are all numbers, so it adds them each to `total`, resulting in `6`. Finally, it executes `return total;`, and this value is assigned to `n` in the original invocation. This will then be added to its copy of `total`.

There does seem to be an error in the code. This line:

```
else if (typeof n === "function")
```

should be:

```
else if (typeof element === "function")
```

Otherwise, it tries to test the type of the uninitialized variable `n`. This allows you to provide a function as an argument to `flexisum`, and it will call the function to get the value to add into the sum.

Comment: So, if I understood it, when statement below **isArray** condition is executed, that condition cease to matter because arguments are now numbers and **for** statement loops through them, so through **else** statement **n** evaluates to that values and is assigned to **total**. I think I understand it now, thank you very much. It seems that I focused too much on **apply** method, or that I'm dumb sometimes. :|

Comment: Each branch of the `if/then/else if/else` deals with a different type of argument, and gets the value to add to the sum in an appropriate way for that type.

Comment: Well, it seems that I need to practice more examples with recursion. 
Thank's again for your help and time.